# Trying to recieve a string through a broadcast in an activity from a service, not seeing anything

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, broadcast

Here's my code below.  The first bit of code is for my activity.  I put a click listener on a button in that activity that starts my service.  Right now, I just want to see that I can recieve strings from that service so here is my code trying to do that.  I put a "hello world" broadcast in the oncreate of the service to test.  Can anyone spot the issue?  The service code is below the activity code.

```
package homeBrewChatter.Calcs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.List;

public class Hop_Timer extends Activity {
    private TextView timerOut;

     private BroadcastReceiver onBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
                Hop_Timer.this.timerOut = (TextView)Hop_Timer.this.findViewById(R.id.display_time);
                Hop_Timer.this.timerOut.setText("RECIEVED");
            }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hoptimer);

        Button setVars = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_alarm_button);
        setVars.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Hop_Timer.this.timerOut = (TextView)Hop_Timer.this.findViewById(R.id.display_time);
                //Hop_Timer.this.timerOut.setText("working so far");
                startService(new Intent(Hop_Timer.this, Hop_Timer_Service.class));
            }

        });
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(onBroadcast, new IntentFilter("mymessage"));
    }
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(onBroadcast);
    }  
}

package homeBrewChatter.Calcs;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class Hop_Timer_Service extends Service {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int length_minutes;
    private boolean timer_running;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    public String currentTime = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        length_minutes = 0;
        timer_running = false;
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("Hello World"));
    }

    public void setTime(int mins) {
        length_minutes = mins;
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimerTask);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimerTask, 100);
    }

    private Runnable mUpdateTimerTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final long start = startTime;
            long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            int seconds = (int) (millis/1000);
            int minutes = seconds /60;
            seconds = seconds %60;
            if(seconds < 10) {
                currentTime = "" + minutes + ":0" + seconds;
            } else {
                currentTime = "" + minutes + ":" + seconds; 
            }
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(currentTime));
            mHandler.postAtTime(this, start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the receiver setup in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: I do not.  So new to Android, didn't realize anything other than activities and services needed to be in there.  Going to check that out now.

Comment: Wow, guess I also need something in there for the intent I use to start the service in my activity.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your actual question, the `Intent` that you are broadcasting does not match the `IntentFilter` you are using in `registerReceiver()`. Since your `IntentFilter` says it is looking for `"mymessage"` `Intents`, your `Intent` that you broadcast needs to have the `"mymessage"` action. Right now, one of your `Intents` has an action that is based on the current time, which is unlikely to be received by anything. The other has an action of `"Hello World"`.

Beyond that:

- By default, broadcasts are broadcast to the entire device. If you are intending to broadcast to the entire device, please use an action string that is namespaced to your app (e.g., `homeBrewChatter.Calcs.mymessage`). If you are not intending to broadcast to the entire device, please use `setPackage()` on the `Intent` that you broadcast to keep it within your application.
- Since `Service` is a `Context`, you do not need to use `getApplicationContext()` in your `Service` for your broadcasts.
- You do not appear to be calling `startTimer()`.
- It is infrequently a good idea, in production code, to have a `Service` whose primary job is to sit and watch time tick by. `AlarmManager` is a more common solution here, so your `Service` can be in memory only when it is adding actual value to the user.
- You start the service, but never stop it.

Comment: Thanks for all this, I'm still learning and using this project to teach myself.  Going to look over everything you said very closely.